# How to pass the nested service and get the response from angular factory to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-services

Here I have make the Http Request and get the response from first Service call and pass the response of first service inside the second service and get the response and to controller.

I got the response , how i could get into controller.

```
app.factory('logHomeService', function () {

        var getHomeService = function (LoginService, HomeService) {
            return
            {
                 LoginService.After("user", encodeURIComponent("pass"))
                  .then(function (response) {
                      debugger;
                      $stateParams.User = "admin";

                      var mydata = response.CT1SessionObj;


                      var DefaultModelObj = { cobj: mydata};

                      HomeService.pageLoad(DefaultModelObj)
                     .then(function (response) {
                         $rootScope.CT1SessionObj = response.mydata;



                     }, function (response) {
                         console.log("LoginService" + response.data);
                         alert(response.Message);
                     });

                  },

                      function (response) {
                          console.log("Home Service" + response.data);
                          return response.data;
                      });
                return response.data;
            };
        };
        return {
            getHomeService: getHomeService
        }

});

app.Controller('HomeController',function($scope,logHomeService)

{


this.logHomeService = logHomeService;
}
```

here   this.logHomeService = logHomeService return the method in factory ,how i get the response result from second service

I need to return home service response to controller, console.log("Home Service" + response.data);

Answer (score 1):

You need to use promises and then listen for the resolution in your contoller.

```
app.factory('logHomeService', function($q) {
  var getHomeService = function(LoginService, HomeService) {
    // create a promise object
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    LoginService.After("user", encodeURIComponent("pass")).then(
      function(response) {
        $stateParams.User = "admin";
        var mydata = response.CT1SessionObj;

        var DefaultModelObj = {
          cobj: mydata
        };

        HomeService.pageLoad(DefaultModelObj).then(
          function(response) {
            $rootScope.CT1SessionObj = response.mydata;
            // resolve the promise
            deferred.resolve( response );
          }, 

          function(response) {
            console.log("LoginService" + response.data);
            // reject the promise if there is an error
            deferred.reject( response );
            alert(response.Message);
          });
      },

      function(response) {
        console.log("Home Service" + response.data);
        // reject the promise if there is an error
        deferred.reject( response )
      });

    // return the promise
    return deferred.promise
  };
  return {
    getHomeService: getHomeService
  }
});
```

First inject `$q` into the Factory. Then return the promise from the the `getHomeService()` method.

The promise is resolved in 3 locations, 2 rejections and 1 resolve. The rejections can be used to do something in the controller when the call fails.

Next update your controller to listen to the promise.

```
app.Controller('HomeController', function($scope, logHomeService){
  this.logHomeService = logHomeService;

  this.logHomeService.getHomeService().then(
    function(successResponse){
      // success
    },
    function(failureResponse){
      // failure
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thanks grant you make my day. In Factory have used two service , in the service i have used promises, but i am not used in factory.

```
var service1 = function ($http, $q, configAPI) {  
    var crContractApi_Url = configAPI.crContractApi_Url;
    this.pageLoad = function (params) {
        var result = $q.defer();
        params.obj.data = null;
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseurl + '/reatiler/retailer',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: JSON.stringify(params)
        })
       .success(function (response) {

           result.resolve(response);
       })
       .error(function (response) {

           result.reject(response);
       });

        return result.promise;
    }
```

like that used in service2. Is thera anyother way